Geometry question relating to circles (How to prove $H$ and $I$ are on radical axis)

Let $D$ and $E$ be two points on the sides $\overline{\text{AB}}$ and $\overline{\text{AC}}$, respectively, of a triangle $\text{ABC}$, such that $\overline{\text{DB}} = \overline{\text{BC}} = \overline{\text{CE}}$, and let $F$ be the point of intersection of the lines $\overline{\text{CD}}$ and $\overline{\text{BE}}$. Prove that incenter $I$ of triangle $\text{ABC}$, orthocenter $H$ of triangle $\text{DEF}$ and the mid points of the arc $\overset{\huge\frown}{\text{BAC}}$ of the circumcircle of the triangle $\text{ABC}$ are collinear.


The following is completely my try. Here I have drawn two perpendicular from $C$ and $B$ to $\overline{\text{BE}}$ and $\overline{\text{CD}}$. Now $\overline{\text{BX}}$ will also be angle bisector of angle $\angle{\text{CBA}}$ and so orthocentre of $\text{FBC}$ will be incentre of $\text{ABC}$. Now, $\text{EM}$ perpendicular to $\text{FD}$ is drawn (I didn't draw $M$ because that would be hazy)  and so $\text{EMYC}$ are concyclic and similarly $\text{DNXB}$ are concyclic. I want to show that $H$ and $I$ lie on radical axis of the two concyclic circles. Is my thought process correct? If yes, then can you give me a hint to proceed?
(Sorry for bad English).

Can you clarify the definition of point $M$? All I see is that $ EM \perp FD$, which allows for a lot of points. Did you want $M$ to be on $DC$?

Yeah yeah that altitude for DEF

(The notation for the hint applies to a general triangle, and not for the notation used in this setup. In that regard, there is some abuse of notation.)
Hint: For a general triangle $ABC$ with altitudes $AD, BE, CF$ intersecting at orthocenter $H$, we have
$$AH \cdot HD = BH \cdot HE = CH \cdot HF.$$
One quick way of seeing this is that $ABDE$ is concylic, with $AB$ as the diameter.
One way to remember this is that $H$ is the radical center of these 3 circles.

 (Now back to using the notation in the problem)
Corollary:
 We are given that $H$ is the orthocenter of $DEF$, so $HE \cdot HM = HD \cdot HN$ (where $M, N$ are the foot of the altitudes), thus $H$ lies on the radical axis.


 OP identified that $I$ is the orthocenter of $FBC$, so $IY \cdot IC = IX \cdot IB$, thus $I$ lies on the radical axis.


ABDE concylic with AB as diameter?

@ShubhayanKuila Make sure you read the note about notation. $D$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $A$, and $E$ is the foot of the perpendicular form $B$, so $ \angle ADB = \angle AEB = 90^\circ$, so $AB$ is the diameter of the circle containing $ABDE$.

Ok I am sorry.Got it
